# Voxel cone tracing directional light soft shadows

Tags: opengl, shadow, voxel

I'm currently trying to implement cone traced soft shadows as described in section 8.3.1 of [this](http://maverick.inria.fr/Membres/Cyril.Crassin/thesis/CCrassinThesis_EN_Web.pdf) paper.

I've got the hierarchical mip-mapped voxel structure in a 3D texture, voxelized by drawing the Sponza scene in the fragment shader, and storing the "voxel fragments" into the 3D texture. The mip-mapping is done in the compute shader.

The author explains how to create soft shadows for point lights and area lights, which are quite straight forward to understand, but he doesn't explain directional lights, which is what the Sponza scene uses.

For point lights, the cone is traced from the point light source and its radius is increased as it traverses towards each part of the scene, described as a "volume" in the scene. However, directional lights do not have a specific light source point, only a direction. How would I translate this concept to work with directional lights? The cone would have to be a different shape, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm being too naïve, but maybe you could compute a bounding sphere for the scene and consider a single cylinder that passes through the center of the sphere with the same radius, oriented according to the light direction. Then you proceed as with point lights (or spotlights) but instead, keep the radius constant (that is, a cylinder instead of a cone).

Answer (score 0):

If not already fixed you could try marching from your query point(so one cone) until you reach a edge of your 3D texture. Since the texture probably have a high size you could consider marching with a parameterisable step size.
To generate soft shadows, generate additional random samples closely to your query point should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of (infinite) directional lights you want to trace a tight cone towards the light and accumulate the opacity. If the opacity reaches 1.0 it is completely blocked. If the cone exits the scene wide AABB you can also safely terminate the cone tracing and return the occlusion which will be used to determine how much shadow falls at the origin of the cone.

The cone aperature here will then control how soft the shadows will become.